# linq collation conflict issue

Tags: linq-to-sql

I'm using linq to SQL and when I run this query

```
        var lstData = from s in dataTrackDB.datas
                      join m in dataTrackDB.mkts on s.mktcode equals m.mktcode
                      join n in dataTrackDB.mktnews on m.mktcode equals n.oldmktcode
                      select new data
                      {
                          AccountDes = m.account,
                          commodity = s.commodity,
                          date = s.date,
                          daysvalid = s.daysvalid,
                          mktcode = s.mktcode,
                          mktDes = n.mktdesc,
                          price = s.price,
                          prodid = s.prodid,
                          statecode = s.statecode,
                          subcommodity = s.subcommodity,
                          supprecode = s.supprecode,
                          units = s.units
                      };
```

I will get "Cannot resolve the collation conflict between "SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS" and "Latin1_General_CI_AS" in the equal to operation" . I'd be thankful if someone guide me how should I write the linq query?

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

The problem lies in `collation` of your columns in Database, change them to the same collation.

setting collation on columns could affect the comparison operators in sql.

http://www.sqldbadiaries.com/2010/10/31/changing-sql-server-collation/

http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2008/12/20/sql-server-change-collation-of-database-column-t-sql-script/

Comment: Is there a way to force the collation through Linq, as you can in SQL? I have two databases, neither of which is allowed to change.